# How can I sell all my vendor trash easily?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Vendor trash, the fun flavor-text filled spice of MMOs, is filling up my bags all too often.  It is usually mixed in with items I want to keep.  Is there an easy way to sell all my <strike>worthless grey junk</strike> *valuables* to vendors?

Comment: How do you plan on telling the system which you want to keep and which you don't?

Comment: @Mufasa as in WoW, grey = junk and *always* safe to sell.

Comment: I know. I thought you weren't talking about "worthless grey junk" but "valuables" instead? In other words, greens or better?

Comment: @Mufasa: I think its dragon age that allows you to mark items as junk at any point and then sell all junk at a vendor. It would certainly be easy to keep track of what you are junking if you could tag it as such when you get it. Still, its not in this game. I am commenting mainly because your first response seemed to be "well how would you do that" when asked how to do something and was just observing that if it is built in there are nice ways to do this sort of thing. :)

Comment: @Chris: Yes, tagging loot as you pick it up would solve the problem if they added that to the game. Though I feel like that is probably overkill, especially considering other issues in the UI that are in more desperate need of fixing. I "tag" it by dragging items I want to sell to the end of my inventory so I know it is safe to sell when I get back to a vendor. It doesn't add any significant time to organize it that way.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't even make a top 10 of things I'd want them to do right now. Further down the line maybe but the onyl time I really have a problem is when I try to remember if I remembered to swap some kit for a companion and have to resummon him, and check. Not the end of the world by a long shot and I am very thankful for the ability to send my companion to sell trash at any time. That is truly inspired. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can ask your companion to sell your junk items for you.  Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up your crew page, then press the button (on the right side of the active companion) to sell all junk items . Or, alternatively, right click on your companion's portrait and select "Sell Trash Items".

When you do this, your companion will leave for 60 seconds with the items, then return with credits. You can do this from anywhere, so assuming you don't need your active companion for a fight you can do other stuff while he's gone.  When he returns, he'll be active again (no need to resummon).  There are additive per-character Legacy perks, Legacy of Leadership I and II, that reduce this to 30 seconds and 5 seconds respectively.

Your companion will not sell items above "gray" level.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mag, I did quite a poor job there by looks of it.

Answer (score 3):

Since patch 1.6.2 there is an option "Sell junk" available at vendors, in the right bottom corner of the vendor screen (close to Repair all, which is in the left bottom corner), which does exactly what you want.